# How can i change the permission of my Microsoft PPT so I could embed it in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed a microsoft powerpoint presentation on my portfolio page, in an iframe HTML tag. However, this is what is displaying inside the iframe:

[image]

How can I change my ppt's permissions so I could publicly display it inside an iframe?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it, I was sharing the document through my business microsoft account's onedrive, and I had to transfer the document over to my personal account's onedrive and share it though there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).